# Off-topic close reasons

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, migration

I finally saw a question that could use *Closing > Off-Topic > Belongs on tex.stackexchange.com*:

> [image]

Some observations:

- *Belongs on superuser.com* appears to be a duplicate since its available on another screen
- *Belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com* and *Belongs on meta.stackexchange.com* don't seem to warrant their own reasons (or I have not been encountering those off-topic questions during reviews)
- *Belongs on dba.stackexchange.com* and *Belongs on sharepoint.stackexchange.com* don't seem to warrant their own reasons (or I have not been encountering those off-topic questions during reviews)

Again, they are only observations from performing reviews. I don't know what the site moderators frequently encounter when they move stuff.

Would it be possible to remove some of the lesser used pre-supplied reasons in favor of more popular, pre-supplied responses. The two I think that would be most useful are:

- security.stackexchange.com
- crypto.stackexchange.com

Or better (perhaps): would it be possible to offer a drop down of the related sites? This option has the benefit of providing metrics so that statistics can be developed. But it also probably requires some coding changes, and I'm not trying to pile work on the site developers.

Retaining *Belongs on superuser.com* seems OK to me (as does *Belongs on serverfault.com*), but I don't understand why its provided on multiple screens.

This appears to be related: [What should the new default off-topic close reason be?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250041/what-should-the-new-default-off-topic-close-reason-be), but it does not address the existing, less frequently used reasons and the duplication of close reasons on different screens.

@hichris provided a better reference at [More options when flagging for migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration). However, I'd rather have a dropdown with available sites (rather than hammering moderators as suggested with: *If you feel strongly a question belongs on a site that isn't listed, then there is a way to do this -- flag them for moderator attention instead!*).

Comment: @hichris123 - yes, that's a much better discussion than I found.

Comment: oh I'd love more options - the ones I see most needed are codereview.stackexchange.com, programmers.stackexchange.com and askubuntu.com

Comment: @sevenseacat - are you certain tex.stackexchange.com is *not* your number one choice?

Comment: If you ever do work with Sharepoint or Database optimisation, although there is some overlap, you'll find a lot of historic questions on StackOverflow that would now belong on the sister sites. So both DBA and Sharepoint migration paths are definitely valid. I've certainly used them both in the past.

Comment: suggestions should be dynamic on tags

Comment: @sevenseacat, programmers used to be one of the listed options. It was removed because of overuse. I agree with you, though there is a long discussion about this (can't seem to find it now though).

Comment: Flagging questions because they are 'duplicates' also appears to be duplicate. Once in the main flagging screen and once in the screen 'It should be closed for another reason'.

Comment: And cs.stackexchange.com also fits a lot of questions in [algorithm]

Comment: There is the write-in reason which can be used to suggest another site in the SE network.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler as far as the using the write in reason to suggest migration to another site, I got ` declined - Please use standard close votes or close flags for this instead of flagging for moderator attention.'`  when I tried this. So for now I'm just not flagging these migratable questions, because I don't know what to do with them. Everything I've seen which is a candidate for migration belongs on stats.stackexchange, which is not an option.

Comment: Also codereview.stackexhange.com would be a reasonable off topic reason!

Answer (score 17):

"Belongs on Meta Stack Exchange" option was a side-effect of the [MSO/MSE split](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014/) that happened earlier today. I removed it.

The rest come from the migration stats on Stack Overflow. Those sites, with the exception of Meta Stack Overflow since site metas are always an available path, are (or at least were the last time these paths were reviewed) the most frequent destinations for migrations from Stack Overflow.

These can be reviewed, we can look at the stats, and I hope a few others chime in here with their thoughts.

(On a side note, the "belongs on Super User" migration option and the off-topic close reason look similar, but only one will actually move the question over to Super User. The latter is for questions that may be best asked on SU, but aren't good enough to migrate outright.)

Comment: "On a side note, the "belongs on Super User" migration option and the off-topic close reason look similar, but only one will actually move the question over to Super User" - that's interesting. I never knew there was a difference. I kind of (incorrectly) assumed if there was a community consensus, then the question was migrated. I bet lots of other folks never made the distinction.

Comment: Why isn't it just "this isn't about programming" and "please migrate to X" (this should be as an option under "not about programming", with "other" being a generic off-topic close)? What if somebody asks a question about socks? From the close reasons it looks like socks are on-topic.

Comment: @bjb568 Close reasons aren't meant to enumerate EVERYTHING. "isn't about programming" was also far too generic. We had just one off-topic close reason before and it didn't work out too hot in the long run. If you encounter a situation that's not covered by the *most common* reasons, just write a custom one in.

Comment: What I meant is that common close reasons are migration. Don't want to migrate? Fine, find a better close reason (too broad, opinion based, recommend a tool, unclear). You can't find any? Fine, then "isn't about programming". Isn't about programming should be a last resort, for the good questions that still aren't on-topic on this, or any migration sites.

Comment: @bjb568 [Migration should (almost) never be your first choice.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/)

Comment: No. Comment, edit, downvote, close, and vlq should be considered first.

Answer (score 2):

- Keep SharePoint
- Keep DBA
- Keep or drop Super User, but don't replace it with Security or Crypto
  (perhaps something else? No good suggestions come to mind)

Explanation:

I've voted to migrated many times more questions to SharePoint or DBA than the number of questions I've encountered that might even remotely be a candidate for Security or Cryptography.

This is from non-tag-specific browsing - the tags I'm interested in don't get any questions for which these reasons may apply, except maybe Cryptography (which is ironic), but then again, I ignore a ton of tags, so maybe one of those makes me miss most of the Security or Cryptography questions (although nothing seems to stand out as particularly probable candidates). I also ironically ignore all SharePoint tags.

I personally prefer the non-migration Super User close reason, so I don't mind that one going too much - I agree that one of the Super User choices should go.

Comment: Wow, this is the complete opposite to my experience.