# How do I indicate that a question belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com?

Tags: support, close-reasons, migration

A few minutes ago, I encountered this question on SO:

[How to solve Big-O Notation for prime number function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23361957/how-to-solve-big-o-notation-for-prime-number-function)

It seems like a fine question, but as it concerns computer science rather than a programming issue, it seems like it's more suited for programmers.stackexchange.com.

I tried to indicate this by clicking **close -> off topic -> This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network**, but the five options presented are *meta, superuser, tex, dba,* and *sharepoint*, with no option to select any other site.

It seems like a fairly common scenario for certain SO questions to be better suited for the Programmers site, but what should one do in this situation?

Comment: Problem with this common scenario was that Programmers ended up getting lots of low quality or off-topic questions (they are rather strict about what they do and do not allow there - read their [help centre docs](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). The result was that the option was removed.

Comment: @rene - that will not get it migrated.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl

Comment: Also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134636/update-migration-path-list-for-non-moderators

Comment: I assumed we left it to the OP to repost the question without involving a moderator @Oded

Comment: @rene - We don't like cross posting. And sometimes, a user can't delete a question (say, if it got an upvoted answer). Past history has shown that many SO users have a very poor understanding of Programmers and what is on-topic there. I would be weary of taking the migration advice of any user who isn't a participant of the migration target site.

Comment: Thank you both for your responses. So, @Oded, you would recommend against informing this user that in future, questions of that nature would be better suited for Programmers.SE? (I am not an active participant of that site, but I think I have a pretty good idea of what its focus is).

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted

Comment: @JLRishe - If you do understand the scope of Programmers, by all means point people there, but do mention that they should read the help centre docs before posting (this really applies to any Stack Exchange site - see what's on-topic before posting off-topic and getting stuff closed).

Comment: The don't [migrate crap rule](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225006/add-a-dont-migrate-crap-migration-path-to-all-sites) applies here...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Off-topic close reasons](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250056/off-topic-close-reasons)

Answer (score 8):

One thing you shouldn't do is add comments suggesting that the OP reposts the question on the other site. The only time this might be acceptable is when the question is clearly off topic for Stack Overflow and doesn't have any answers. What we don't want is for the answers to the question to be split between different sites.

If you think the question should be on Programmers (or anywhere that's not a direct migration path) please flag the post with the "other" reason and explain why you think it would be better off there. However, the fact that you're not an active member of the target site will count against your flag - it's one factor we use in deciding whether the question should be migrated or not.

However, you will have to be 100% that the question is both off topic for Stack Overflow and a good question. Poor quality questions should just be closed as poor quality and not dumped onto another site. This particularly applies to sites where there is a migration path.

Please note, there is an overlap between sites - especially Stack Overflow and Programmers so while it may be that a question should have been asked on one site rather than the other it's not necessarily the case that it has to be migrated.

BTW - I'm a moderator on both Stack Overflow and Programmers.

Comment: Moderators do not seem to be of one voice on whether or not we should flag: "If you really feel a question should be on a different site and it doesn't have answers yet, I'd honestly recommend telling the OP to delete it on SO and re-post it on the other site rather than flagging in hopes that we'll move it for you." (Quoted from animuson's answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227202/241526).)

Comment: @Louis It can be a pain, but if a question has answers and is on the wrong site then migration is the only option to ensure that information is kept together.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that the presence of answers makes a difference.

Answer (score 4):

**Unless** you are an active participant on programmers.stackexchange.com **and** have good knowledge of what is and is not on topic there, **you should not suggest that a question be moved there.**

I've come across questions on SO that had been downvoted or were on the verge of being closed, or had been closed already. Some well-meaning but uninformed commenter suggested posting on Programmers, and the OP took this suggested at face value. In no case was the question, which was rejected on SO, successful on Programmers.