# activity of flagged question?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, last-activity

There was a question related to [asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net)[design-patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design-patterns) I had voted to close. Well, I wanted it to be migrated to programmers.stackexchange.com. So there was a comment laid in the question post after that close-vote process.

I was searching for that comment post in my activity list, but couldn't find it. Now I can't trace back to that question. Did the poster remove the post, or, was it migrated?!

Comment: "I've come across questions on SO that had been downvoted or were on the verge of being closed, or had been closed already. Some well-meaning but uninformed commenter suggested posting on Programmers, and the OP took this suggested at face value. In no case was the question, which was rejected on SO, successful on Programmers..." ([How do I indicate that a question belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252709/839601))

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're referring to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23870579/one-method-with-many-behaviours-or-many-methods that was deleted by the asker, taking your comment with it.

They re-asked it on Programmers: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/241134/one-method-with-many-behaviours-or-many-methods

Comment: Yes. Now Would I be able to find it as fast as you did? :)

Comment: @deostroll - No, unless you had it still in your browser history. Moderators can see deleted comments, and work back from there.