# What to do when a question is off-topic for all of the listed sites in the close flag?

Tags: discussion, flags, migration

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23598128/open-links-of-others-apps-in-my-browser-app) in the low-quality post queue. I thought it would be a much better fit for the Android Stack Exchange site, but unfortunately that site isn't an option in the flag screen.

I've seen the discussion [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250056/off-topic-close-reasons) about how the list of sites is chosen for that page, but what am I supposed to do when the question doesn't fit into any of those sites either? I chose Super User since that seemed to be the closest. What should I do in the future and is it possible to add a free response box to the list of sites in that list?

Answer (score 21):

You shouldn't choose Super User just because that is closest. This is the reason why there are only a select group of sites available - it's to mitigate stuff (potential crap) being migrated to places it should never go.

You can choose Off Topic / Other and leave a custom reason. Your reason will show up in the list for any reviewers who come after you, so they can choose it too.

[image]

Alternatively, if you think it's a **good question** (remember, don't migrate crap!) that will be a good fit on a specific site then flag it for ♦ moderator attention and mention which site it should be migrated to. Note that doing this has no guarantee of success - the moderator who processes the flag may decline it, and the target site may also say they don't want it.

Comment: It seems like that option is only available when voting to close. Could it be added as a flag option?

Comment: @connor +1. And I remember I used to be able to do it before (but I don't remember which way though), but no more. What happened? I now need like a lot of rep before being able to flag it that way, which is a bit, IMO, a nonsense.

Comment: As I learned the [hard way](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288335/1584012), the "other" option is only available for reputation over 3k. As [some moderator suggests](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251654/1584012), you should rather leave a polite comment and inform the OP about the site you think that question is on-topic on.

Comment: For the second time yesterday, I followed the suggestion of flaggin the post for a moderator's attention, specifying that the reason to close was not listed as a flag, and the response I got was "declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention". So, no, don't flag for a moderator's attention a question that should be migrated to another site not listed in the flag options.

Comment: @giusti I'm a mod on a different SE site, so this sounds like you're not quite doing it right. You need to include a proper reason, not just *"the reason I think is not on the list"*. You have to mention **why** it should be on the other site, and as I mentioned in my answer it is **still up to the mod** who processes the flag.

Comment: To be more specific, my message to the moderator was *"The question does not fit any flag options. It should either be closed or migrated to math.stackexchange.com"*

Comment: @giusti Keep it short, just say *"Belongs on math.SE"*. But even then it is still up to the individual mod. That mod might message the mods on Math and ask them, they might refuse to accept the question. Or the mod might just turn down your request if they disagree.

Comment: And now the "Other" option is gone, so there really is no recourse but to say that the question is blatantly off-topic or take no action.

Comment: This option not being available is exemplary of common SE community failure.