# Flag Question belongs to another site in the Stack Exchange Network

Tags: discussion, support, flags, migration

I would like to know what flag I have to take if a Question is clearly Off Topic, but would match greatly to an other Site in the SE-Network, which I can't choose from the list.

> [image]

Do I have to choose

> Blatantly off-topic (this question has nothing to do with programming)

then

and add a Comment like please ask here or there?

[This is the question where I did not know what to do.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430983/problems-logging-in-ubuntu#comment37799787_24430983)

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254414/what-to-do-when-a-question-is-off-topic-for-all-of-the-listed-sites-in-the-close

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The question in question is a poor quality question and shouldn't be migrated anywhere.

Before considering whether a question would be better off on another site you have to ask:

> Is this a good question?

If the answer is "no" then just flag/vote to close in place with a general "off topic" reason. You might consider leaving a comment point to site X but also mention that they need to write a better question.

If the answer is "yes" then flag using the "other" option and let the mods know that the question would be better off on site X. **Don't** suggest site X in the comments - that only leads to cross posting and duplicate creation when the question does get migrated.

Comment: @AstroCB I'm not sure I follow your reasoning there.  Flagging this question as blatantly off-topic would seem to be an appropriate use of this flag unless I am reading your linked question incorrectly.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I could certainly be wrong (as I didn't implement the flag), but the general sentiment that I got from that question was that the new reason should be used only when something really doesn't belong anywhere. There are specialized flags for migration to other sites, and the questions like this that I've seen generally say to either flag it for moderator attention and describe where it should go or just downvote and leave. What I got from Shog9's answer  was that it should be used as a general-purpose off-topic flag (i.e. closed *because* it's off-topic in many ways, not migrated).

Comment: @AstroCB and the question in question is blatantly off-topic and should not get migrated (because it sucks).  You have 3 choices (1) Good Question, Existing Migration path - vote/flag to migrate. (2) Good question, No existing migration path - flag as "other" and let the mods deal with it.  (3) Bad question - flag to close as blatantly off-topic (or vote to close with a custom reason if you have 3K).

Comment: @psubsee2003 Fair enough; I didn't look at the question too closely, but you're right: if it were migrated to Ask Ubuntu, it would probably just be closed there anyway.

Comment: What is the "other option" you mention in your answer?