# The asker is directed to another Stack Exchange site, even though it would be off topic there

Tags: discussion, flags, migration

Just came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29086666/nova-launcher-squashed-app-drawer-on-nexus-10), he was asking about something specific to a specific android app.

I told the OP (in a comment) that the question would be better placed on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) & I also flagged the question with custom flag reason 'Should be moved to Android Enthusiasts'.

Minutes later, it was put on hold as off-topic, **but with a message and a link to get help on Super User**, which resulted in him asking the [question there](https://superuser.com/questions/890371/nova-launcher-squashed-app-drawer-on-nexus-10) (it is now migrated), where it is also off-topic.

---

The problem is that the text under the 'On Hold' heading says:

> This question appears to be off-topic. The users who voted to close gave this specific reason:
>
> - Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/about).

That link encourages new users to ask their question somewhere where it is not suitable.

---

**It would be good if the text were reworded somehow, to inform the asker (and others) that there are options other than Super User also,** as the text is somewhat obsolete, as it was written when sites like Android.SE did not exist.

And / or a drop down after selecting the `Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow...` close reason allowing us to pick any site would be nice.

Comment: Related, if not a dupe: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277872/2821954

Comment: Many people just can't be bothered with a custom close reason, or maybe don't know that the android.SE site exists ...

Comment: Even when delete-voters intentionally recommend sites, they often don't realize that the question would be off-topic at the recommended site. This has happened to me several times, occasionally leaving me with nowhere to ask a question that I've felt would fit in at *multiple* sites.

Comment: [Also related](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254414/what-to-do-when-a-question-is-off-topic-for-all-of-the-listed-sites-in-the-close?rq=1).

Comment: see also: [When recommend an appropriate site for off-topic question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268722/839601)

Answer (score 32):

The comment about Super User is in the standard close reason.

Some of us are unhappy that it's there as it causes problems like this, but there hasn't been a consensus reached as to what it should be replaced with.

Comment: It would be nice if the comment about Super User could be (optionally) replaced with some other (custom) text when closing. Ah well..

Comment: Yes, it would be useful if I could refer people to other SE sites than the few listed (more easily)

Comment: @Sobrique I believe the official policy is "no automatic delegation to beta sites," which is why so few are listed.

Comment: Makes sense. Would be nice if there was a close-without-migrate for that scenario though.

Comment: @Angew, Android.SE is not beta, so the question could have been moved there..

Comment: A drop down after selecting that option allowing us to pick any site would be nice.

Comment: Srsly? It links to Super User in all cases? That's mental.... at least remove the link if you're not sure what other link to put in?!

Comment: @Gabe: It won't happen. They even _removed_ some options (e.g. Code Review) because it was apparently making it too easy for people to mis-migrate and that was a common mis-migration path (although I never really bought into that rationale, myself).

Comment: Easy solution, link [to the sites list](http://stackexchange.com/sites#) instead. Let the asker find where it should go. Maybe give the people closing it the option to specify(without a link) a site.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau I've got a [suggestion to that effect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210545/213963) over on MSE.

Answer (score -2):

> This question appears to be off-topic. The users who voted to close gave this specific reason:
>
> - Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on one of the other [StackExchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#). Check the Super User, Programmers site(s).

Where Super User and Programmers can be changed by the people closing the question. It wouldn't be a link to avoid directing there but at least give a idea to the asker which site(s) their question might be on-topic. If none are recommended, nothing would appear after the link to the SE sites list.

Or to not let closer recommend any site, link to the sites list. I would prefer having the option to recommend but I can see why it wouldn't help in some cases.

Comment: please spare this text off Programmers, it's already abused enough.  Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: It's just an example. Those aren't links, they are the sites that people closing the question would recommend. The standard text wouldn't include it, it would be constructed with the recommended sites of people closing. If none are recommended, nothing would appear after the link to the SE sites list.

Comment: Better not to mention any site by name,

Comment: Could be that way too, to avoid any mistakes by closers that wouldn't know where it would be on topic and recommend a site anyways

Comment: "Stack Overflow can completely swamp us with ["post this on Programmers.SE" comments](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7154/31260 "we even had to introduce a chat bot for identifying when Programmers is mentioned on Stack Overflow") and when even a fraction of those questions show up here (and get closed) it's problematic."

Comment: If you are going to say that something is off topic, and they should check (an)other site(s), you will get the person posting on multiple sites - ***even if it is not on topic there*** and possibly *all* the other sites that are vaguely related (this happened last night where one person posted on SO and then was directed to post on CS, P.SE, and Workplace as other options because it was off topic on SO... and it was off topic on all the other sites too). Unless you can migrate it without comment, don't mention another site.  Flag it if it is a good question for migration.

Comment: Seriously, I love the idea of redirecting to the site list rather than a specific site, but please, just don't name any sites at all. Then it's as broadly applicable as possible.

Comment: @sphanley The problem with telling someone "go somewhere else" is that when the question is poor quality to begin with and "somewhere else" also closes the question. Suggestions, flags and migrations should *only* be done when the question is of sufficient quality to not get closed. That no 'somewhere else' is specified doesn't mean that people will avoid using this for another 'too localized' or 'minimal understanding'. Care is needed to make sure that good and proper direction is given to the OP when the question is off topic that they aren't bounced around.