# How to flag off-topic post belonging to non-listed StackExchange site

Tags: support, scope, stack-exchange

During review I found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141797/many-app-in-android-how-do-diable-this-app-so-these-can-not-autostart) that belongs to [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/). Wanted to flag off-topic/belongs to other site, but could not, because of SE limitations. After digging meta for [duplicates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251652/flagging-migration-should-include-more-options) and duplicates of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251652/flagging-migration-should-include-more-options) and similar questions, I found the [what-to-do-know](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254415/1584012) answer. Which was outdated, because for off-topic, the "other reason" option was removed since then.

I do not want to rage-quit triaging, but I got to the edge of my patience.

1. What to do with these off-topic posts today?
2. How to avoid rookie reviewers spending ages learning about this SE limitation?
3. Should I add a new answer to the [what-to-do-know meta-post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254415/1584012) with things I learned in this current post?

Comment: OK, @martijn-peters, you found yet another duplicate of this kind of question. That does not even have an answer to "what to do know". How does your flagging improve learning new reviewers what to do in this case?

Comment: @rene I think the other reason is only available for users with >3k with close vote privs. Don't think you can flag-vote to close as an other reason.

Comment: @rene Probably that needs more reputation than what I have

Comment: So, spending yet another 10 minutes reading all the answers and comments on the answers on the post @martijn-peter suggested, I found out what he meant: Do not close such questions, just comment them politely.